# Load more data on click of an item in Paging 3 library

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow, android-paging-3

I'm using the paging 3 library, I want to load the next page items on click of a button in my recycler.

```
        //for first case it will be null, then we can pass some default value, in our case it's 1
        val pageNumber = params.key ?: DEFAULT_PAGE_INDEX
        PAGE_NUMBER = DEFAULT_PAGE_INDEX
        return try {
            val response = tasksApi.getTasks(
                token = "Bearer " + NicoPrefs.getSSOAccessToken(),
                status = pagingTasksInput.status,
                type = pagingTasksInput.type,
                activity = pagingTasksInput.activity,
                sort = pagingTasksInput.sort,
                sortBy = pagingTasksInput.sortBy,
                pageNumber = if (pagingTasksInput.pageNumber > 0) pagingTasksInput.pageNumber else pageNumber,
                pageLimit = pagingTasksInput.pageLimit,
                assignee = pagingTasksInput.assignee
            )
            val data = pagedResponse?.result
         
            LoadResult.Page(
                data.orEmpty(),
                prevKey = if (pageNumber == DEFAULT_PAGE_INDEX) null else pageNumber - 1,
                nextKey = null
            )
        } catch (exception: IOException) {
            return LoadResult.Error(exception)
        } catch (exception: HttpException) {
            return LoadResult.Error(exception)
        }
    }
```

I have added a footer

```
map {
      it.insertFooterItem(TaskDto(footer = "FOOTER", description = "Load more"))
    }
```

When i click on the "Load more", updating the page number and making an API call (page limit is 50 in my case)

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            testViewModel.getPagingTasks(getAssignedTasks)
                .collectLatest { response ->
                    Timber.d("paging item = ${assignedTasksPagingAdapter?.snapshot()}")
                    assignedTasksPagingAdapter?.submitData(
                        response
                    )
                }
        }
```

I have to append the next 50 items to the existing 50 items on the recycler view. how do we achieve this?

Answer (score -2):

Page fetch in Paging is triggered by item access via  `.get(index)` calls on your presenter (e.g., PagingDataAdapter). If you need to avoid page fetch while accessing items, you can call `.peek(index)`